# Перестали показываться stack trace на Laravel 5

Tags: php, сервер, laravel

Всем привет. Все нормально работало до сегодняшнего дня. Сегодня вместо stack trace показывается просто Ошибка сервера 500 На сайте произошла ошибка при получении http://mysite/services. Возможно, сайт временно недоступен или настроен неправильно.
Я ошибку нашел, но как вернуть stack trace? Причем, если запускаю `artisan serve` и запускаю проект на localhost, то ошибки показываются нормально. Получается, что-то сломалось в apache?

Comment: Может кусочек лога апача или php-fpm покажите?

Comment: спасибо, что напомнили про логи ) совсем из головы вылетело, что они есть. ))) В логгере laravel была ошибка - почему-то  не получалось открыть файл лога за сегодняшний день. Удалил его и все заработало. Спасибо огромное!